# How to get numbers of views for your perosnal post from LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

is it possible to get numbers of views for your own post from LinkedIn API?
I have found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/network-update-social-actions#retrieve-social-actions.
But this give you ability only to see numbers of Likes and Comments.
How about the views, basically I want to get this [image: this] number.

Thank you.

Comment: A workaround (which has a few disadvantages) would be to simply scratch it, e.g. with JSoup if you're using Java.

Comment: This number, is public only for the owner page, I can't see no one else number of views, except my own posts. And obviously I can't ask user to leave their passwords to me. So I can use only official authentication.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? can you enlighten us? thanks!